# Removing certain parts of a files name using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been attempting to remove a certain string from a bunch of files but I am unable to do it. The part I want to rename is the .english in my files. How would I do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhRKG.png

Comment: Protocol: Include graphics using the picture icon rather than a link. For a list, include as text to enable cut-and-paste. Highlight by selecting and pushing `{}`. No code provided -> solution has no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.english.*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "newname=%%b"
 ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%b" "!newname:.english.=.!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Because your string splitting is at periods, `.`, I'd offer the following methodology.

In cmd.exe:

```bash
for %g in ("*.english.wav") do @for %h in ("%~ng") do @ren "%~g" "%~nh%~xg"
```

From a batch file:

```bash
@For %%G In ("*.english.wav") Do @For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do @Ren "%%~G" "%%~nH%%~xG"
```

---

As your question is unclear as to the intended final filename.

If you wanted to replace `.english` with something else, *lets say `.german`*, rather than simply removing it, then change:

`"%~nH%~xG"`, or `"%%~nH%%~xG"`

To:

`"%~nH.german%~xG"`, or `"%%~nH.german%%~xG"`